# Installing PostGIS with GDAL 3.0.4

Tags: 18.04, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 18.04 using these instructions: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-12-on-ubuntu/

Now I'm trying to install PostGIS extension:

```
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-3
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgis : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-12-postgis-3 : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

GDAL was installed sometime earlier. I checked gdal version like this:

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
```

Also, I tried installing libgdal-dev but it says it is already newest version:

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgdal-dev is already the newest version (3.0.4+dfsg-1~bionic0).
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

`libgdal20 (2.2.3+dfsg-2)` is available from `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

The `postgis` package is available from postgresql repository and depend on `libgdal20` provided by the universe repository.

Comment: postgis is also from the universe repository, but it doesn't return an `unable to locate` error message.

Comment: @karel the `postgis` package is available from postgresql repository and depend on `libgdal20` from universe.

Comment: @karel see http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgis/ . You can reproduce the error by enabling postgresql repository and disabling universe.